# jQuery function in javascript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jeditable

I got some DIV's I'm editing with 'jeditable' which works perfectly!
Now I want to give my users an alert to ask them if they really want to edit this post.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function jeditable() {

    $("div[title='Article']").click (function() {
        var Edit;
        Edit = confirm("Editing article?");

        if (Edit == true) {         
                $('.edit').editable('x2.php', {
                    cancel : 'Cancel',
                    submit : 'OK',
                    onblur: 'ignore',
                    });          
            } else {
                alert("Canceling edit..");
            }
     });      
});
</script>
```

1)When the alert pops and I cancel it, nothing happens (intended).

2)When I click "OK" in the alert nothing happens as well.

3)When I clicked "OK" once, the function in my 'if' works no matter if I check "OK" or "Cancel" in a second click in the alert.

I would like to only make my text editable after the user clicks "OK" once.
(Later on I want to make an image clickable instead of the text itself, but because that throws same error I try to solve this way first)

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Problem still alive!
I changed to not make the article itself clickable fo the "confirm" but some img instead. That way it works perfectly, even with another element so trigger the confirm to make '.edit' editable. Workaround found, but still would be interested in a solution for the other way :)

Comment: What's with the multiple `$(document).ready()`s?

Comment: was a failure in copy pasting there is no second ready :)

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the jeditable library , therefore here is what I would do to achieve your requirement

```
$(document).ready(function()
    $("div[title='Article']").click (function() {
        if (confirm("Editing article?")) {         
                $('.edit').editable('x2.php', {
                    cancel : 'Cancel',
                    submit : 'OK',
                    onblur: 'ignore',
                });         
         }       
    });     
});
```

Comment: Look well! I will try this later Firefox is not playing Javascrip atm

Comment: Tried it but still got the issue, that text gets only at the second click editable

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function jeditable() {

    $("div[title='Article']").click (function() {
        var Edit;
        Edit = confirm("Editing article?");

        if (Edit == true) {         
            $('.edit').editable('x2.php', {
                cancel : 'Cancel',
                submit : 'OK',
                onblur: 'ignore',
                });      
        } else {
            alert("Canceling edit..");
        }        
    });  //<<< this was closing out the function BEFORE the else.
});
```

Comment: Wier but when I do that my alert disappears

Comment: Edited, your statement is a bit heavy but the problem is you're closing the click event before the else statement.

Comment: ah ok :) I will try this lateron somehow my firefox doesnt play naymore javascript atm not even alert :D maybe hes tired

Comment: Now when i refresh the page I always get the "canceling edit.." alert

Comment: Umm you didn't actually copy both document.readies that I had did you? Didn't notice the typo until just now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a "}" after the end of the else clause. If you look at the error console in the browser I think you will have an error indicating this.

```
    if (Edit == true) {         
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.edit').editable('x2.php', {
                cancel : 'Cancel',
                submit : 'OK',
                onblur: 'ignore',
                });         
            }); 
        } else {
            alert("Canceling edit..");
        }
     } // <-- add this in
 });
```

Comment: No I got no error that I' missing that "}" why missing? all "{" are closed in my code

Comment: Actually this answer is close, the problem is where things are closing, not that they aren't closing.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need "$(document).ready(function" after if

```
 $(document).ready(function jeditable() {
    $("div[title='Article']").click (function() {
        var Edit;
        Edit = confirm("Editing article?");

        if (Edit == true) {         
            $('.edit').editable('x2.php', {
                cancel : 'Cancel',
                submit : 'OK',
                onblur: 'ignore',
            }); 
        } else {
            alert("Canceling edit..");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah sorry was too much pasted :)